# Determine whether the improper integral $\int^{\infty}_{0} x/(1+x^3)$ is convergent or divergent.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I've tried comparing this integral, but I didn't come to an answer, since the improper integral is smaller equal than the integral 1/x^2. Does anyone see how I can compare this to another integral or how I can say whether the integral is convergent or divergent?

Comment: Split it up into the part $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$ and then compare again with $\frac{1}{x^2}$ on $[1,\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

Since$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac x{x^3+1}}{\frac1{x^2+1}}=1$$and since he integral$$\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx$$converges, then so does your integral.

Comment: This doesn't take into account possible divergence at $0$ (which is not hard to do but this argument doesn't suffice to do it).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How can it diverge at $0$? Here, we are integrating a continuous function such  that $0$ belongs to its domain. So, the integral can only diverge at $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, like I said, it's not hard to do and you just did it. But your argument in the answer, as written, doesn't do it, and the OP's attempt using $\frac{1}{x^2}$ fails because it introduces a divergence at $0$ that wasn't there before. This is why leoli1 in the comments suggests splitting into $[0, 1]$ and $[1, \infty)$ which will also work fine.